# Printing all the integers from 0 to n in in descending order order using recursive method

Tags: recursion

I made a little program to practice recursions, but I can't get it to work as intended as you can see. In its current state, the program kinda works but not like I want it to.

What I am looking for is to print values from int N to 0 in descending order rather than from 10 to N as it is currently in the code.

```
private static void DescendingRecursion(int n)
    {

        if (n == 10) // Base case
            return;
        else {
            DescendingRecursion(n + 1);
            Console.Write(n + " ");
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DescendingRecursion(0);
    }
```

(output: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0)

Comment: Shouldn't the recursion start with the maximum value and return a string and the current count -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass the maximum value and pass `n - 1` on each recursive call instead? E.g.

```
private static void DescendingRecursion(int n)
{
    if (n < 0) { // base case
        // optional: ensures a newline at the end
        Console.WriteLine();
    } else {
        Console.Write(n + " ");
        DescendingRecursion(n - 1);
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DescendingRecursion(5);
    // Output: 5 4 3 2 1 0
}
```

**EDIT**

An alternative method that sticks closer to your original code, though I definitely prefer the above code to this:

```
private static void DescendingRecursion(int max, int n=0)
{
    if (n <= max) {
        DescendingRecursion(max, n + 1);
        Console.Write(n + " ");

        // optional: ensures there's a newline at the end
        if (n == 0) {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DescendingRecursion(5);
    // Output: 5 4 3 2 1 0
}
```

**EDIT2**

A version that returns a `string` instead of printing:

```
private static string DescendingRecursion(int n)
{
    if (n < 0) {
        return "";
    }
    return n + " " + DescendingRecursion(n - 1);
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DescendingRecursion(5));
    // Output: 5 4 3 2 1 0
}
```